# How to setup input for local multiplayer without split-screen in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: input, unreal-4, unreal

To bind actions and axes in the character blueprint class, I may have multiple such character instances for each new APlayerController.  Merely 1 Action Name (e.g. avoiding `UseSkill_P1`, `UseSkill_P2`, etc) is required for each character by adding the node in the Player Controller. However, for more functionality the same is required in cpp.

#### What I've tried:

When I bind actions and axes (*delegates*) in the `APlayerController`'s  `SetupInputComponent` (e.g: `InputComponent->BindAction("Attack", IE_Pressed, this, &AMyController::DoSomething);`, then spawn multiple players with `UGameInstance::CreateLocalPlayer(index, err, true)`, the editor will crash on pressing Play in Editor (*Alt+P*).

The error thrown during runtime is: `Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)` and referencing the line where the first `ActionBind` appeared, e.g: `UE4Editor_MyProject!AMyController::SetupInputComponent() [d:\path\to\project\source\private\mycontroller.cpp:66]`

---

A common solution can be found [in this wiki post](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Local_Multiplayer_Tips) it seems. In short, overwrite `GameViewportClient` and set it as default, then within, overwrite `InputAxis` and `InputKey` and increment the player controller index for each input device (*gamepad*) used.

As mentioned previously, this would require the project to specify a unique Action Name for each player index e.g. `Attack_P4`.

---

There is also some confusion that needs to be cleared up.

- An `AController` will not be created for each input device connected.
- 1-viewport-multiplayer isn't supported as split-screen. (*Weird naming, but good for search engines*).
- Spawning new Local Players is generally done in your override of `AGameMode::BeginPlay`. I made it up to the deriving BPs of my Game Mode to call `CreatePlayers` to create up to the set amount of players.
- Setting `Skip Assigning Gamepad to Player 1` will allow keyboard to be used for player 1.

---

Hopefully there are some common best practices to tackle this problem. Any suggestion is very much appreciated!

PS Here is [the related unreal answers hub question](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/880263/how-to-setup-input-for-local-multiplayer-without-s.html).

Answer (score 1):

I tried the template approach, where it overrides `SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)` in the `ACharacter` derived class, and then bind delegates by calling e.g: `PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Jump", IE_Pressed, this, &ACharacter::Jump);`

For some reason this reminded me to include `Super::SetupInputComponent();` in my `APlayerController::SetupInputComponent` and the bindings started working. The editor wouldn't crash any longer.